# Syntax error when creating table in Vertica with PYODBC

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc, create-table, vertica

I am trying to load a big list of sql queries into a table in Vertica using PYODBC. Here's my code:

```
tablename = DVXTEMP.my_table_name
sql = my_sql_query.strip().strip(';')
samplesize = 1000

createstring =   'CREATE TABLE %s AS %s \n limit %s;' %(tablename, sql, samplesize)

cursor.execute(createstring)
```

when I print createstring and run it in Toad, it works fine. when I try to execute it in pyodbc, it gives me the following error:

```
'Syntax error at or near "DVXTEMP" at character 1\n (4856) (SQLExecDirectW)'
```

We are using Vertica Analytic Database v7.1.2-6

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Try removing the semicolon on the query.

Comment: Just tried, same error.

Comment: Are you able to connect via isql (unixodbc client) and run a query? The only other thing I can think of is maybe to str() the strings going in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) did you import pyodbc?

2) did you define "cursor" from "pyodbc.connect"?

```
import pyodbc

DB = '[string for dbfile]'
DRV = '[string of which driver you are going to use]'
con = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={};DBQ={}'.format(DRV,DB))
cursor = con.cursor()
##build SQL code and execute as you have done
```

Try SQL commands after you can connect without an error.

3) I use pyodbc for mdb files (MS Access) and some of my queries will not run unless I put single quotes outside double quotes on table/field names.

```
mytbl_1 = "mytbl"
SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' + mytbl_1
print SQL
```

print result -> SELECT * FROM mytbl

(this fails)

```
mytbl_2 = '"mytbl"' #single quotes outside of double quote
SQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' + mytbl_2
print SQL
```

print result -> SELECT * FROM "mytbl"

(this string gets passed w/o error works for me with MDB files)